# How can I remove items from the custom dictionary?

Tags: keyboard, autocorrect, dictionary

Like an idiot, I accidentally added a word to the dictionary, and now my phone likes to use the incorrectly spelt word. Is it possible to remove incorrect items from the custom dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to remove a word from the dictionary is resetting your complete dictionary by going to

Settings -> keyboard -> typing settings -> reset suggestions

Comment: He is right. I wish there was a list of custom entries with the ability to remove specific ones, but you can't

Comment: Joe lots of people would like these features but microsoft has other priorities

Comment: Here's a UserVoice suggestion for it.  There are several, but this one seems to have the most votes: [Dictionary Manageability](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2422948-dictionary-manageability)